# How to write a full property that is nullable

Tags: javascript, typescript, nullable

Sorry if it is a duplicate question, I can't find it...
I want to write out a property, but still keep it nullable.

I want

```
public foo?: string;
```

to be (but nullable)

```
  private _foo: string;
  public get foo(): string {
    return this._foo;
  }
  public set foo(v: string) {
    // some logic with 'v'...
    this._foo = v;
  }
```

Where do I put my `?` or is there another way?
I tried with `Nullable<string>` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
private _foo: string|null;
public get foo(): string|null {
  return this._foo;
}
public set foo(v: string|null) {
  this._foo = v;
}
```

Comment: I still get the error that when I declare the object, the Property 'foo' is missing in type ' {...}'.

Comment: You need to set `?` into your interface